# Divergent or convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

If 
$$A_n = \frac{n(n+3)}{(n+1)^2}$$  then is the sum of the sequence $\sum(A_n)$ convergent or divergent?

Comment: The tag ([tag:summation]) is supposed to be about finite sums (see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/summation/info).) The tag ([tag:sequences-and-series]) is for infinite series.

Comment: Well I am really glad u told....I had no such prior knowledge

Answer (score 5):

Hint: In order for $\sum A_n$ to be convergent, it is required that $A_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I just had one doubt then (1/n) tends to 0 as n tends infinity even then the summation of 1/n is divergent.....how come this happen ?

Comment: The converse is not necessarily true. Convergent implies tends to 0. Tending to 0 does not imply convergent.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

The terms of the series tend to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $\lim A_n=1$ and the limit for convergent series is...

Comment: Just like mine.  ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes: as simple argument, as it is possible. :-)